# how to create twodimensional arrays non-repeat numbers with recursive java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, recursion, return

I want use recursive function for check non-repeat
  numbers in NxM array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N, M, i, j;

    N = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 3);
    M = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 3);
    int matris[][] = new int[N][M];
    System.out.println("Setir=" + N);
    System.out.println("Sutun=" + M);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            matris[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 900 + 100);
            System.out.print(matris[i][j] + " ");    
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.   What do you expect to happen, and what are you observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {
static boolean isInitial = true;
static boolean isnChanged = true;
static Integer maxN = null;

static Integer matrix[][];
static List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    generateMatirx(3, 3);

    print2D(matrix);
}

public static Integer[][] generateMatirx(int m, int n) {

    if (isInitial) {
        matrix = new Integer[m][n];
        isInitial = false;
        --m;
        maxN = --n;
    }
    matrix[m][n] = checkAndAdd();
    if (n > 0) {
        isnChanged = true;
        --n;
    } else {
        isnChanged = false;
        if (maxN != 0)
            n = maxN;
    }
    if (!isnChanged && m > 0) {
        --m;
    }

    if (n == 0 && m == 0) {
        matrix[m][n] = checkAndAdd();
        return matrix;
    }

    return generateMatirx(m, n);
}

public static Integer checkAndAdd() {
    Integer integerRand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3);
    if (list.contains(integerRand)) {
        return checkAndAdd();
    } else {
        list.add(integerRand);
        return integerRand;
    }
}

private static void print2D(Integer mat[][]) {
    // Loop through all rows
    for (Integer[] row : mat)
        // converting each row as string
        // and then printing in a separate line
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What do you want exactly to happen during the check? Simply to check if there are any repeating items and returning true if there are any and false if there aren't or something else?